Flutter Stripe checkout issue
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3 (1)
This is the error i am facing. Given below is the stripe code.
After entering the card num and all details when I click on continue, it redirects me to the visa web view from where it is returning 'some error occured' it is not able to register my payment
I am using flutter_stripe: ^10.1.1
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:product_iq/consts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

class StripeService {
  static var res;
  static Future<void> initPaymentSheet(BuildContext context) async {
    // final paymentSheet = PaymentSheetTest();
    // await paymentSheet.initPaymentSheet();
    try {
      final paymentUrl = Uri.parse(
          '${MyConsts.baseUrl}/subscription/payment-intent/plan/1/duration/Monthly');
      http.Response response = await http.post(
        paymentUrl,
        headers: MyConsts.requestHeader,
      );
      res = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        debugPrint(res.toString());
        final ephemeralKey = res['ephemeral_key']['secret'];
        final clientSecret = res['payment_intent']['client_secret'];
        final id = res['payment_intent']['customer'];
        Stripe.publishableKey = dotenv.env['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']!;
        await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
            paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          customFlow: false,
          paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
          customerId: id,
          merchantDisplayName: 'Product Cohort',
          googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(
              merchantCountryCode: 'IN', currencyCode: 'inr', testEnv: true),
        ));
        await Stripe.instance
            .presentPaymentSheet()
            .then((value) => debugPrint("Success"));
        debugPrint('1');

        displayPaymentSheet();

        debugPrint('2');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error initializing payment: $e')),
      );
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())),
      );
    }
  }

  static displayPaymentSheet() async{
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {

        //Clear paymentIntent variable after successful payment
        res = null;

      })
          .onError((error, stackTrace) {
        throw Exception(error);
      });
    }
    on StripeException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error is:---> $e');
    }
    catch (e) {
      debugPrint('$e');
    }
  }
}


I tried to print success but it's getting stuck and returning error occured.

did solve this problem?
